# Spring security: register users during runtime

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I have a service with two end-points:

1. **Public Endpoint**: anyone can access it, and open a user account (register)
2. **Protected Endpoint**: only a registered user can access it, by using the *Authorization Header* as a part of HTTP POST request

Use-Case:

- A user first hits the **public endpoint** and opens the account by HTTP POST a JSON containing the `userName`. The service then generates the password, and passes it as a JSON response back to the user.
- After the user has got the password back from the service, he should use this `password` (along with his `userName`) to access the **protected endpoint** by passing his credentials in the *Authorization Header*

Now, obviously, there is a requirement to register new user **during runtime**.

The problem I am facing is that when the first user registers on a public endpoint, after that moment there is no more authenthication needed to access the protected endpoint! Every credentials will work, and even a request without *Authorized Header* will work. I am not sure why I am getting this kind of bad behaviour, so any advice on how to fix it will be great!

**Public Endpoint to open user accounts**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<UserCreatedResponse> create(@RequestBody String userName) {
        // generate user password
        String password = service.generatePassword();

        // save the user to the local repository
        service.save(userName, password);

        // use SecurityService to add a new user token --> something fishy here!
        security.login(userName, password);


        // returns response with a new user password
        return new ResponseEntity<UserCreatedResponse>(
                new UserCreatedResponse(password),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**UserService.java** used to save the user to the repository

```
public void save(String userName, String password) {
    repository.save(new User(userName, passwordEncoder.encode(password)));
}
```

**SecurityService.java** used to store credentials for login: I am not sure if this is correct

```
public void login(String userName, String password) {
        // usrDetailsService is the instance of UserDetailsService.java
        UserDetails usrDetails = usrDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usrDetails, password, usrDetails.getAuthorities());

        // authenticate token with the given account details
        authManager.authenticate(token);

        if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
            // provide authentication info to the context
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        }
    }
```

**UserDetailsService.java**

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // this is my custom User class
    User user = repository.findById(userName);

    // and this is org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPasswordHash(), Collections.emptySet());
}
```

**Protected (authorized) endpoint**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
public String hello(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {
    return "Hello, authenticated!";
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user") 
                            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Again, the wanted behaviour is:

- Create new user account on "localhost:8080/user"
- And then hit "localhost:8080/hello" which requires authenthication for any user registered above, and otherwise responds with *Unathorized* response

What is missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone can help? It's like it logs-in the user when the "/user" controller gets hit to register new user, and then after i call the authenticated controller "/hello", it doesn't ask for authentication anymore, while it should! How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

What does your security configuration look like?
You can specify which pages should be open for registration:

```
  /**
   * Configures the access rights for the application.
   *
   * @param http the HttpSecurity context of the application
   * @throws Exception some exception.
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        //Which URLs are available without any authentication
        .antMatchers("/about", "/help", "/imprint", "/register", "/registerExp", "/login**").permitAll()
        //Restrict access rights for any relative URL behind /admin/ to the ADMIN role
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        //Any request needs to be fully authenticated (remember me does NOT suffice!)
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
        //Specify the login process.
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureHandler(authenticationHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).ignoringAntMatchers("/console/**");

    //Disables header security. This allows the use of the h2 console.
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }
```

Comment: Added SecurityConfig class

Comment: Basically I have all the needed stuff as your Security Config, I just don't have the "formLogin()" part, as I don't have any login forms, it's a pure service and authentication should be based on Authentication Header. I don't understand why it doesn't ask for login details when I hit "/hello" controller after registering on "/user" endpoint. Before registering "/hello" needs authorization, but after registering it does not. While it should... any idea?

Comment: It's because you are authorising the new user after registration. You call `
        security.login(userName, password);` Which sets the authentication with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);`. So your user is able to access all protected sites without logging in again

Comment: Well if I remove that part, then it asks for authenthication but the credentials are never recognized.

Comment: Hmm not sure if that helps, but i use the userDetailsManager to create a new user: 
`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User newSpringUser =
                new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                        user.getEmail(), encoder.encode(user.getPassword()), userAuthorities);
        userDetailsManager.createUser(newSpringUser);`

When i need my application user (not the spring user) i just compare the username or email or whatever from the security context with my application users

Comment: And where do you put that code? Can I have it directly in the registration controller? And how do you pass that user to the security components of the app? Do you store it in your repository?